# CGI DLL (built in Delphi) physical path

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I deployed an CGI DLL built with Delphi 2007 on the Windows 2008 server. Internally I need to use the current DLL path.

Normally I can use `GetModuleFileName` or `GetModuleName`, but on the server they both return:

```
\\?\c:\my\correct\path
```

Why the first 4 characters? It looks like a network path? Is there any way to exclude those first 4 characters?

Comment: That's a [UNC path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNC_path#Uniform_Naming_Convention), isn't it? Anyhow, I bet some of [the shell lightwight path functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559(v=vs.85).aspx) can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pertinent [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247.aspx) is this:

> **Maximum Path Length Limitation**
>
> In the Windows API (with some exceptions discussed in the following
>   paragraphs), the maximum length for a path is `MAX_PATH`, which is
>   defined as 260 characters. A local path is structured in the following
>   order: drive letter, colon, backslash, name components separated by
>   backslashes, and a terminating null character. For example, the
>   maximum path on drive D is "D:\some 256-character path string"
>   where "" represents the invisible terminating null character for
>   the current system codepage. (The characters < > are used here for
>   visual clarity and cannot be part of a valid path string.)
>
> **Note**  File I/O functions in the Windows API convert "/" to "\" as part
>   of converting the name to an NT-style name, except when using the
>   "\\?\" prefix as detailed in the following sections.
>
> The Windows API has many functions that also have Unicode versions to
>   permit an extended-length path for a maximum total path length of
>   32,767 characters. This type of path is composed of components
>   separated by backslashes, each up to the value returned in the
>   lpMaximumComponentLength parameter of the GetVolumeInformation
>   function (this value is commonly 255 characters). To specify an
>   extended-length path, use the "\\?\" prefix. For example, "\\?\D:\very
>   long path".
>
> **Note**  The maximum path of 32,767 characters is approximate, because
>   the "\\?\" prefix may be expanded to a longer string by the system at
>   run time, and this expansion applies to the total length.
>
> The "\\?\" prefix can also be used with paths constructed according to
>   the universal naming convention (UNC). To specify such a path using
>   UNC, use the "\\?\UNC\" prefix. For example, "\\?\UNC\server\share",
>   where "server" is the name of the computer and "share" is the name of
>   the shared folder. These prefixes are not used as part of the path
>   itself. They indicate that the path should be passed to the system
>   with minimal modification, which means that you cannot use forward
>   slashes to represent path separators, or a period to represent the
>   current directory, or double dots to represent the parent directory.
>   Because you cannot use the "\\?\" prefix with a relative path,
>   relative paths are always limited to a total of `MAX_PATH` characters.

As long as you are calling Unicode versions of Windows API functions, then there's no need to strip the `"\\?\"` prefix. Because the path that you have been handed is a valid path.

As we discovered in the comments, you were calling an ANSI version of an API function. And when you do that, the `"\\?\"` prefix is not valid. So, stick to Unicode API functions and it's all good!

Comment: thanks everyone,

I was trying to convert the UNC to physical path but it turned out I don't need to.

Using SafeLoadLibrary instead LoadLibrary for some reasons worked without worry about the UNC path.

Comment: yes, I was actually using PAnsiChar for the file label, internally SafeLoadLibrary calls LoadLibrary using PChar I guess this made the difference. Technically it's better to use SafeLoadLibrary for a service anyway. Thanks, I need to wait 8hr. before answering to my own question. Thanks again.

Comment: @batman: I'm quite sure David wouldn't mind you accepting his question! :)

Comment: I wanted to answer my own question because I thought this was the correct way to leave documentation of what I did to resolve the issue. I will leave the comment above then.. thanks again.

Comment: You can answer the question if you want, but I'm not sure what you could add. Talking about `SafeLoadLibrary` and `LoadLibrary`, for example, would not really relate to the question you asked. For sure it relates to the code that is prompting this, but it's not actually related to the precise Q that you asked.